why am i getting negative value for effective gas price?
May 27 10:51:16.745 DEBG Trying again after eth_getTransactionReceipt RPC call for transaction 0x77e3b240fb0e665edc49b4f2464095ae69a18a4760cf2f654103237ad1c3d3b3 failed (attempt #5) with result Err(Decoder("Error(\"invalid hex character: -, at 0\", line: 0, column: 0)")), provider: chiliz-rpc-0, component: EthereumPollingBlockIngestor
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG web3::transports::http] [id:17] sending request: "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"eth_getTransactionReceipt\",\"params\":[\"0x029ae8430c7bb914013d662c8d8f0f6ff3e53da8975a692a4eba372065f9d87f\"],\"id\":17}"
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG hyper::client::pool] reuse idle connection for ("https", rpc.chiliz.com)
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::io] flushed 249 bytes
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::io] parsed 10 headers
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::conn] incoming body is chunked encoding
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::decode] incoming chunked header: 0x409 (1033 bytes)
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG hyper::proto::h1::conn] incoming body completed
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG hyper::client::pool] pooling idle connection for ("https", rpc.chiliz.com)
[2024-05-27T10:51:19Z DEBUG web3::transports::http] [id:17] received response: 
"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":17,\"result\":{\"blockHash\":\"0xb0cfe12f406a4662e79f6f37ea9ed8b05289443fd02cabe320494d45119a8600\",\"blockNumber\":\"0xcc0cd2\",\"contractAddress\":null,\"cumulativeGasUsed\":\"0x73976\",\"effectiveGasPrice\":\"-0x246139ca800\",\"from\":\"0x84af28c88be1916ceb199394dd6a1493a1287ada\",\"gasUsed\":\"0x56ca\",\"logs\":[],\"logsBloom\":\"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\"status\":\"0x1\",\"to\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001000\",\"transactionHash\":\"0x029ae8430c7bb914013d662c8d8f0f6ff3e53da8975a692a4eba372065f9d87f\",\"transactionIndex\":\"0x3\",\"type\":\"0x0\"}}\n"



I suggest you to add more context to your question, it would be useful to know your code, the language, library and the environment.
